# I want to keep only 5 days data and delete rest of the data if it is less than the retention date. Need to remember each day 2000000 row generate

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_delete_data()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE loop_counter INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE retain_days datetime;
  DECLARE delete_days datetime;
  SET loop_counter=(SELECT ROUND(count(*)/100,0) FROM data2 WHERE datetime<(SELECT  DATE_ADD(min(datetime),INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM data2));
  SET retain_days=(SELECT DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 5 DAY)); -- 5 days data will keep
  SET delete_days =(SELECT  DATE_ADD(min(datetime),INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM data2); -- check old data from table data2
        WHILE i <= loop_counter DO
            IF retain_days>delete_days THEN
                DELETE FROM data2 where datetime<delete_days LIMIT 1000;
            END IF;
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;  
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

> I want to keep only 5 days data and delete rest of the data if it is less than the retention date. Since each day data generate almost 2000000 rows that is why it is difficult to delete whole data by one shot. That is why I want to delete 100000 data in each loop.
> Here,
> loop_counter variable used to find how many loop we should use for this day data.
> retain_days variable define to find retention date
> delete_days variable define to find deleted date.
> based on retain_days and delete_days varoable data will retain and delete.
> Fnally this procedure will call by event every 1 day.

My code loop is not working as expected. Need expert solution.
If is there any performance issue to delete data like this please let me know. Thanks In Advance

Comment: You wrote that your code was not working as expected, but failed to explain what this mean! Do you get an error message? Do youget unexpected output?

Comment: Loop is not working. Only one time it is deleted those data.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Don't do it this way. Your database will have an order of magnitude more work to do when you do multiple `SELECT`s on this huge table. Just run a single delete, it will be much faster this way.

Comment: Manually delete is time consuming. I have 3-4 month data. I want to delete those automated way. @Louis do you have better any solution than this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to delete rows in batches of 1000, delete with limit in a loop while row_count() = 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an event that runs once a day:

```sql
CREATE EVENT purge_old_data
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
    STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    COMMENT 'Delete rows older than 5 days'
    DO 
BEGIN
  DELETE
    FROM data2
  WHERE `datetime` < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 DAY);
END;
```

You should not use a loop to delete smaller chunks. In SQL databases loops actually make performance worse. If you have to delete 100s of millions of rows in the first run it is really not a problem for MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITION BY RANGE` with each partition being, say, 2 hours' worth of data.  Then `DROP PARTITION` will *very* rapidly drop data -- *much* better than `DELETE`.

More on using partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Alternatives:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

In particular, the second link show how to 'continually' run through the data via the `PRIMARY KEY`, deleting 1000 rows at a time.  Repeat when finished.

Note:  The following is problematic:

```
DELETE FROM data2
   where datetime<delete_days LIMIT 1000;
```

Without  `INDEX(datetime)`, it will spend much of its looking for any rows to delete.  With such an index, there is still the overhead of bouncing between the index and the data 1000 times.  In either case, the 1000 rows must be put into the redo log for the off chance of a crash.

Comment: But does partition support foreign key constrain for mariadb/mysql?

Comment: In this table I have a foreign key constraint because of that unable to do partition. Do you know how to do partition on foreign key constraint table? Please share details document if you have.

Comment: @SheikhWasiuAlHasib - Foreign keys + Partitions -- FKs are not a requirement.  The indexes that the FKs create are useful for performance.  When switching to Partitioning, you should re-think the indexes.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the main queries; I'll advise on indexing.

Comment: @SheikhWasiuAlHasib - Use the second link for advice on how to delete lots of data without using involving partitioning.